# Alamofire cancel sometimes does not work

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have a simple request like:

```
func newRequest() {
    println("CANCEL = \(self.getTime())")
    self.request_.cancel()

    self.request_ = request(method, url)
    validate(statusCode: [200])
        .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
        .responseJSON { [unowned self] (_, _, json, error) in

            if(error?.code == NSURLErrorCancelled ) {
                println("CANCELED!")
            }

            println("DONE LOADING = \(self.getTime())")
            // ...
    }
}
```

As shown above, when new request is invoked, I want previous to be canceled.
And it usually works, but sometimes when previous request is about to end (there is a very short amount of time between logs), it does not.

```
(newRequest) CANCEL = 1436103465.93128
// CANCELED! SHOULD BE HERE
(previousRequest) DONE LOADING = 1436103466.08223
```

To make it work I added a var isCanceled and check whether it is set to true.
I am not sure if it works as it should (it may be too late to cancel) or it is a small bug.

Answer (score 1):

You expectation here is incorrect. The cancellation is not a synchronous behavior. It is asynchronous and needs to hop several dispatch queues before your `responseJSON` closure will be called. Since you are repointing the `self.request_` reference to a new `request`, your previous request is actually going out of memory and your `responseJSON` closure for the previous request will never be executed.

Instead of using a single reference to one request, you could use your `self.request_` property to store the latest request, and use a `requests` set to store all the active requests. Once the `responseJSON` closure is called, make sure to remove the request from the `requests` set. This way, you would keep a reference to all requests until they finished properly canceling.

Believe me, Alamofire cancellation works properly. Our giant test suite agrees.